# Android cardview onclick implementation

Tags: android, checkbox, android-cardview

I had make a list of cardviews that are series of time starting from 0:00 to 23:00 with interval of 15 minutes, that is [0:00 , 0:15, ...., 22:45, 23:00] now I want to implement onClick to the cards and whenever I click on one card there will be a checkbox set in the card with checked set as true, and when I click on another card the previous clicked card checkbox will be set as false and invisible while the new one will contain a checked checkbox

```
public class SuggestTimeCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SuggestTimeCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    List<SuggestTimeList> suggestTimeLists;

    public SuggestTimeCardAdapter(List<SuggestTimeList> suggestTimeLists, Context context){
        super();
        this.suggestTimeLists = suggestTimeLists;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SuggestTimeCardAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.suggest_time_card, parent, false);
        SuggestTimeCardAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new SuggestTimeCardAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SuggestTimeCardAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SuggestTimeList suggestTimeList =  suggestTimeLists.get(position);

        holder.tvSuggestTime.setText(suggestTimeList.getSuggestTime());

        holder.suggest_time_card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //implement the click
                holder.cbSuggestTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.cbSuggestTime.setChecked(true);
            }
        });


    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return suggestTimeLists.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvSuggestTime;
        public CheckBox cbSuggestTime;
        public CardView suggest_time_card_view;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvSuggestTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSuggestTime);
            cbSuggestTime = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbSuggestTime);
            suggest_time_card_view = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_time_card_view);


        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem I have is that whenever I click on one card, for example 0:00, then all cards with increment of 2:15 will be checked, so that 2:15 , 4:30 etc. are all checked, then while scrolling and not clicking anything the checked cards will suddenly become unchecked and random cards are checked. I am confused here , can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In your `SuggestTimeList` class, add an attribute; `isChecked`, like this:

```
class SuggestTimeList
{
   boolean isChecked;
   //// Other attributes and methods...
   public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
      this.isChecked = isChecked;
   }

   public boolean isChecked() {
      return isChecked;
   }
}
```

Then in your Adapter do this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final SuggestTimeCardAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SuggestTimeList suggestTimeList =  suggestTimeLists.get(position);

    holder.tvSuggestTime.setText(suggestTimeList.getSuggestTime());
    if(suggestTimeList.isChecked()) {
            holder.cbSuggestTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cbSuggestTime.setChecked(true);
    }else {
            holder.cbSuggestTime.setChecked(false);
            holder.cbSuggestTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }  
    holder.suggest_time_card_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //implement the click
            holder.cbSuggestTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.cbSuggestTime.setChecked(true);
            for(SuggestTimeList s : suggestTimeLists) {
                 s.setChecked(false);
            }
            suggestTimeList.setChecked(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this solves the problem for not having other cards checked when i click on one card. We will have to define isChecked as false in SuggestTimeList class since it will be a null object if we don't do so. However if I click the second card the first card is still checked in your situation, also after scrolling down and scrolling backup the checked card is unchecked automatically

Comment: It wont be null, I used the primitive `boolean`. It is `false` by default :). Secondly, the problem you have identified can be solved by calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` after  `suggestTimeList.setChecked(true);` in the click listener.

Comment: Can you kindly show me how to use notifyDataSetChanged? i tried using it with my adapter suggestTimeLists but could not get it to work. Thank you

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this made the cards show nothing onClick

Comment: That's strange. The problem you're facing is due to the data being updated but it is not notified. I have edited again, please check.

Comment: Thanks for sticking so long with me, but still the problem is the same

Comment: I am just curious, as why it isn't working, technically it should work.

Comment: I will let you know if I could figure it out